# The function of "doing something" in "be busy doing something"

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, parts-of-speech

I know "busy" can be used with the structure: "be busy doing". For example: I'm busy learning English.

Now, I'm wondering whether "learning English" in this sentence is a gerund phrase or a participle phrase? And what function (adjective/adverb) does this phrase have in the sentence?

Comment: No, there's no gerund in *I'm busy learning English* - where ***busy*** is just an adjective introduced into the simple statement *I'm learning English* within which ***learning*** is a continuous verb form. Gerunds look the same, but we call them gerunds when they function as *nouns* (as for example, *Learning English is hard*, which is the same basic structure as *Diamond is hard*).

Comment: Traditional grammar would call the verb "learning" a present participle in your example, but nowadays it's often called simply a gerund-participle. It heads the gerund-participial clause "learning English", which functions as a depictive adjunct giving descriptive information about the subject "I". Notice how the clause can be dropped with no loss of grammaticality - hence 'adjunct'. It is interpreted with progressive aspectuality (cf. _I am learning English_).

Comment: Traditional grammar would call it a gerund as in the sentence "I happy that you are here" they call the that-clause a noun clause. Lol

Answer (score 1):

Nice question. 
You actually ask if the auxiliary verb (am) refers to the word "busy" or to the word "learning". I think that you asked this question because you assume that  if it refers to the word "busy" then the word "learning" is a gerund, and if it refers to the word "learning" then the word learning is a verb in present participle tense.

I guess that it's not simple to answer on it since not any case in English has rule, but personally I believe it depends on the context and meaning of the phrase. That says, that if you say your phrase in following meaning:

> I am busy learning English. = I am busy in nowadays because I have a lot of learning.

then in this meaning the word "learning" is gerund, since it functions the same as if was written: "I'm busy in learning English".

But if you say your phrase in this meaning:

> I **am** busy **learning** English. = I am busy right now because I'm learning English.

Then, it's as if was written "I'm busy now because I'm learning English" since there is a using of [pronoun](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/pronoun.asp) + [auxiliary verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_verb) in this sentence (I am...), near to the word which ends with -ing ending, therefore it is a **verb** that functions as [present participle](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/spelling/verb-tenses-adding-ed-and-ing).

It cannot be a **gerund**, since the definition of [gerund](http://www.eudict.com/index.php/js/languages.html?lang=en2eng&word=form%20of%20a%20verb%20which%20acts%20as%20a%20noun%20(Grammar)) is "form of a verb which acts as a noun". In your case it does not acts as a **noun** because of the presence of the *pronoun* (I) with the *auxiliary verb* (am) right before the word ends with -ing.

If you wrote "Learning English makes me busy", or "Learning English is easy" then the word "learning" would be a gerund in both of these sentences because they are themselves the 'instead of' the pronoun, the [subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_(grammar)) of the sentence rather than additional to it.

BTW, I found similar question in [this forum](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/busy-preparing-gerund.2987788/) and you can see another opinions.